# 3GPP Cell ID and Cell Type

Tags: lte, cellid, 3gp

I was going through the 3GPP documents, different Cell IDs and Cell Types.

```
CellType  Format
CGI       MCC+MNC+LAC+CI
ECGI      MCC+MNC+ECI
SAI       PLMN-ID+LAC+SAC
TAI       MCC+MNC+TAC
```

For Eg:
ECGI Value = 310-260-328290210

TAI Value  = 310-260-44615

Was just curious, whether we can find the Cell Type given the Cell ID.

If we can, can anyone point me to any resources?